# How to fix NGX-OWL-CAROUSEL-O display in Angular Material <mat-grid-list> Element not displaying until Resizing screen?

Tags: owl-carousel, angular13

Dear Typescript Expertise,
I am using NGX-owl-carousel-o to display touch-drag item carousel in my Angular project.
I have implemented the code as snipped. The issue is when open it there are no carousel displaying on the page, until I resize browser using minimize and maximize button it's displaying.

I hope to get solution and solve this issue soon.

[image: Before resize screen - ngx-owl-carousel-o is not working]

[image: After resized screen - ngx-owl-carousel-o is working normally]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {OwlOptions} from "ngx-owl-carousel-o";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-xl-slider',
  templateUrl: './xl-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xl-slider.component.scss']
})
export class XlSliderComponent implements OnInit {
     // Slider Responsive


  constructor() {

  }  // End Constructor

  // ngx-owl-carousel
  XlSlider: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: false,
    margin: 10,
    dots: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    navSpeed: 800,
    navText: ['', ''],
    nav: false,
    items: 20,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 8000,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 1
      },
      740: {
        items: 1
      },
      940: {
        items: 1
      },
      1440: {
        items: 1
      },
      2640: {
        items: 1
      }
    },

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

```css
// Dashboard Grid
.grid-container {
    margin: 20px;
}

.slider-card {
    position: absolute;
    // top: 15px;
    // left: 15px;
    // right: 15px;
    // bottom: 15px;
}
:host::ng-deep .mat-card {
  padding: 0;
}
.more-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
}
.zero-o {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-card-content {
    text-align: center;
}

// .owl-carousel {
//     width: 100%;
//     height: 100%;
//     padding: 15px;
//     z-index: -2;
// }
// Section radius
.section-radius {
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}

// Zero margin and zero padding
.main-slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 3;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

// 100% width and height
.full-space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="1:1" gutterSize="6px">
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="8" rowspan="4">

            <owl-carousel-o [options]="XlSlider" class="full-space">
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-1.jpg" alt="Test 1"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-2.jpg" alt="Test 2"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-3.jpg" alt="Test 3"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-4.jpg" alt="Test 4"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-5.jpg" alt="Test 5"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-6.jpg" alt="Test 6"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-7.jpg" alt="Test 7"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-8.jpg" alt="Test 8"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-9.jpg" alt="Test 9"/>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template class="item" carouselSlide>
                <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/slide-10.jpg" alt="Test 10"/>
              </ng-template>
            </owl-carousel-o>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
          <mat-card class="slider-card">

            <mat-card-content class="zero-o">
              <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/PD-BT900.jpg" alt="Test 4"/>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
          <mat-card class="slider-card">

            <mat-card-content class="zero-o">
              <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/TWS-2S.jpg" alt="Test 4"/>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
          <mat-card class="slider-card">
            <mat-card-content class="zero-o">
              <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/RB-S30.jpg" alt="Test 4"/>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
          <mat-card class="slider-card">
            <mat-card-content class="zero-o">
              <img class="image-fit" src="assets/img/slider/RC-128a.jpg" alt="Test 4"/>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>


<!-- END Grid -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I applied a few lines of code below it's working.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));}
```

Comment: It's good that you found this, but it's not entirely clear where this bit of code is actually supposed to go.

Answer (score 1):

This happen Because Setting Wrong id **Id must be string** or you can go **without id and ID gets Automatically**

> Every id must have the type string. Otherwise, slides won't get ids what will cause one problem, which appears when the developer uses the option responsive. Slides won't be shown when the width of the screen changes and the carousel has to apply new settings according to the defined breakpoint. This is because the code uses ids of slides in order to assign new data to slides. So if you change the width of the screen and slides disappear, there could be the problem with setting id.
> If ids aren't set explicitly, they will be created automatically.

[Read This Manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o)

Answer (score 1):

Id should be in string inside the corusel.
ex: [id]="'your id here'".   Or  id="your id here"